# Getting "Error: Generic Error. Could not generate specified XSD file!" while trying to get dependent xsd of a wsdl file

Tags: java, wsdl, websphere, jax-ws, websphere-7

I have an EJB Session bean exposed as a webservice:

```java
    @Stateless
    @WebServiceProvider(
            targetNamespace = "http://WSCreateAccountMovementListRequest.ws.mybank.ru",
            serviceName = "WSCreateAccountMovementListRequest",
            portName = "WSCreateAccountMovementListRequestPort",
            wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdl/WSCreateAccountMovementListRequest/WSCreateAccountMovementListRequest.wsdl")
    @ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
    @javax.jws.HandlerChain(file = "handlers.xml")
    public class WSCreateAccountMovementListRequestImpl implements Provider<SOAPMessage> {
...
}
```

This bean is deployed on a Websphere AS 7.0.0.21.
I want the service's client to be able to access the wsdl in order to generate their stubs. But I faced a trouble.
I can access wsdl of the deployed service with no problems, 
but when I try to create a project from the wsdl in SoapUI, I get this error:

> Error loading
>   [http://example.com:9081/WSCreateAccountMovementListRequest/WSCreateAccountMovementListRequest/META-INF/wsdl/WSCreateAccountMovementListRequest/WSCreateAccountMovementListRequestTypes.xsd

If I try to view that xsd in a browser, I get the following:

> Error: Generic Error.
>
> Could not generate specified XSD file!

The xsd file is placed in the same directory as the wsdl file(in `META-INF/wsdl/WSCreateAccountMovementListRequest/` in EJB jar).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, show me how do you making the WSDL file from command line? Is possible that XSD file be creating wrong.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I don't generate any wsdl or xsd files. I use existing ones. Furthermore, I can get all the files(wsdl and xsd) from Websphere administration console by doing "Publish WSDL files" for that service and those files work well in SoupUI. But for some reason websphere couldn't return the xsd file through the service's endpoint URL.

Comment: Maybe those files are wrong location in your path, why not you try to put it in `../web-inf/wsdl/WSCreateAccountMovementListRequest.wsdl` and `../web-inf/wsdl/WSCreateAccountMovementListRequestTypes.xsd` **Hope this helps**.

Comment: I deploy my web service as EJB Session bean packaged in ejb-jar archive, there is no web-inf folder, only meta-inf.